# $f(n)$ is equal to the number of perfect squares in the range $[n^2,2n^2]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_+^*\to \mathbb{Z}_+^*$ such that $f(n)$ is equal to
>   the number of perfect squares in the range $[n^2,2n^2]$. Prove that
>   $f$ is increasing and surjective.

$f(n)\ge 1$ because $n^2$ is always in range. I did a few terms:

$n=1 \to \{1^2\} \in [1,2]\implies f(1)=1$

$n=2 \to \{2^2\} \in [4,8]\implies f(2)=1$

$n=3 \to \{3^2,4^2\} \in [9,18]\implies f(3)=2$

$n=4 \to \{4^2,5^2\} \in [16,32]\implies f(4)=2$

$n=5 \to \{5^2,6^2,7^2\} \in [25,50]\implies f(5)=3$

$n=6 \to \{6^2,7^2,8^2\} \in [36,72]\implies f(6)=3$

$n=7 \to \{7^2,8^2,9^2\} \in [49,98]\implies f(7)=3$

$n=8 \to \{8^2,9^2,10^2,11^2\} \in [64,128]\implies f(8)=4$

$n=9 \to \{9^2,10^2,11^2,12^2\} \in [81,162]\implies f(9)=4$

$n=10 \to \{10^2,11^2,12^2,13^2,14^2\} \in [100,200]\implies f(10)=5$

I wasn't able to spot a pattern to write $f(n)$ as a function of $n$. It seems obvious that $f$ is increasing and surjective, but I can't put it in a formal proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that
$$f(n)=1-n+\lfloor\sqrt{2}n\rfloor.$$

Comment: Thank you, I got it, if $f(n)=m$ then $n^2,...,(n+m-1)^2$ are the squares and $(n+m-1)^2<2n^2<(n+m)^2\implies m-1< n(\sqrt{2}-1)+1<m\implies \lfloor n(\sqrt{2}-1)+1\rfloor=m$ and I think it will be very easy from here.

Answer (score 0):

Let the sequence be $n^2, (n+1)^2,....,(n+k)^2, 2n^2$

Condition that we need is $(n+k)^2 \le 2n^2$

On solving we get $k \le (\sqrt{2}-1)n$

$k=[(\sqrt{2}-1)n]$ , where [ ] represents GI

No of perfect squares between  $n^2$ and $2n^2$=$k+1=[(\sqrt{2}-1)n]+1$

So, $f(n)=[(\sqrt{2}-1)n]+1$ which is an increasing function. And I think, now we can find its range also.

Let us consider a function $f(x)=(\sqrt{2}-1)x$ defined on $R^+$
Being a straight line it's range will be $ y  \in (0,\infty)

f(x) is a continuous function, and if we take the transformation [f(x)] $\in N$

$\Rightarrow$ Range = N

Answer (score 0):

Well, we need $n^{2}\leq (n+i)^2\leq 2n^{2}$ then $0\leq i\leq \lfloor\ (\sqrt{2}-1) n\rfloor$ thus $f(n)=1+\lfloor\
 (\sqrt{2}-1)n \rfloor$. Now note that $f(n+1)-f(n)=0 , 1$ and $f(1)=1$ hence it's surjective and increasing and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Well.  If $n^2 \le k^2 \le 2n^2$ and $k$ is an intger.

Then $n \le k \le \sqrt 2{n}$

And as $\sqrt 2{n}$ can never be an intger

$n\le k < \sqrt 2{n}< \lceil \sqrt 2 n \rceil$

And the number of such integers is more than $\sqrt{2}n-n$ and less than $\sqrt 2n-n + 1$ and so the number is $ \lceil n(\sqrt{2} -1) \rceil$.

Clearly increasing.  If $m < n$ then $m(\sqrt 2 -1) > n(\sqrt 2 -1)$ and $ \lceil m(\sqrt{2} -1)  \rceil \ge\lceil n(\sqrt{2} -1) \rceil$.

Not so clear in is surjective but $\sqrt{2} - 1 < 1$ so

if $f(n) = k = \lceil n(\sqrt{2} -1) \rceil$ Then $n(\sqrt{2} - 1) < k < n(\sqrt{2} - 1)+ 1$ (remember $n(\sqrt{2}-1)$ can never be an integer.

$(n+1)(\sqrt{2}-1) < k + (\sqrt{2} - 1) < k + 1$

So $f(n+1)= \lceil n(\sqrt{2} -1) \rceil\le k+1$.

So it is never possible for a positive integer to be skipped.

And clearly $f(n)$ in not bounded above.